# css - only last child type selector (only one)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to select the very last child of type `<div>` contained into "#myDiv"

```html
    <div id="myDiv">
        <div>
            <img>
            <div>
                <div>text</div>
                <div>text</div>
            </div>
            <div>divFooter</div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <img>
            <div>
                <div>text</div>
                <div>text</div>
            </div>
            <div>divFooter</div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <img>
            <div>
                <div>text</div>
                <div>text</div>
            </div>
            <div>divFooter</div> <!-- I WANT ONLY THIS -->
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
```

I've tried many combinations of `:nth-last-child`,`:last-child`,`:last-of-type`,`:nth-last-of-type()`, but unfortunately I can't select only the last one div (only one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the last `div` *grandchild* of `#myDiv` you need to use two sets of child combinators with the `:last-of-type` selector:

```
#myDiv > div:last-of-type > div:last-of-type
```

Comment: Just for better understand, what if I want to select only last <hr> ?

Comment: @Edward: Then `#myDiv > hr:last-of-type` will do.

Comment: @Santosh Parashetti: Likewise you could say `#myDiv > div:nth-last-child(2) > div:last-of-type/:last-child` and any other combination. But I don't think it's necessary to highlight all the possibilities. I just use of-type for consistency. There's also the possibility that the last hr might not be the last child, but again all that is out of the scope of this question (which I'll demonstrate by not bothering to construct a demo to show this).